# How do I create a centered pure CSS drop down menu that doesn't overlap other menus?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a centred pure CSS drop down menu, but am struggling with the implementation.  Problem summary:

1. The first menu is transparent and overlapping the other, which it shouldn't
2. I'm not able to put the menus side-by side
3. Im unable to centre the menus on the page
4. I'm unable to get rid of the transparent gap between the link background and the edge of the list
5. I'd like to select by clicking on the box surrounding the link. Now I have to click on the link itself.
   [image: Overlapping menu]

Here's a JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/nxq55ppr/1/

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="menuitems">
<div class="menuouter"><div class="menuinner">First menu<ul>
    <li><a class="menuitem " href="#">Lorem</a></li>
    <li><a class="menuitem " href="/#">Ipsum</a></li>
    <li><a class="menuitem " href="#">Lorem</a></li>
    <li><a class="menuitem " href="/#">Ipsum</a></li>
</ul></div></div>
<div class="menuouter"><div class="menuinner">Second menu<ul>
    <li><a class="menuitem " href="#">Lorem</a></li>
    <li><a class="menuitem " href="/#">Ipsum</a></li>
    <li><a class="menuitem " href="#">Lorem</a></li>
    <li><a class="menuitem " href="/#">Ipsum</a></li>
</ul></div></div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
.menuinner { 
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px; 
    border: 2px solid purple; 
    width: 200px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
}
.menuinner > ul { display: none; }
.menuinner:hover > ul { padding: 0; margin: 0; list-style-type: none; display: block; background: #f9f9f9; border-top: 1px solid purple;}
.menuinner:hover > ul > li { list-style-type:none; padding: 5px; display: block;}
.menuinner:hover > ul > li:hover { background: #ccc;}
.menuinner:hover > ul > li:hover > a { color: red; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an updated version of your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nxq55ppr/2/)

I've also added box sizing rule to your css

```
*, *:before, *:after {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

***Changes made***

1. The first menu is transparent and overlapping the other, which it shouldn't

Your `.menuinner` doesn't have background-color, so it appear transparent

2. I'm not able to put the menus side-by side

Your `.menuinner` have a width specified but the parent `.menuouter` have full width

3. Im unable to centre the menus on the page

Your `.menuinner` have an absolute position.

4. I'm unable to get rid of the transparent gap between the link background and the edge of the list

Your `ul` elements has a default top and bottom margin.

5. I'd like to select by clicking on the box surrounding the link. Now I have to click on the link

I changed anchor element from inline to block and give it full width.

Comment: I will, but could you make a couple of comments in your answer regarding the main problems with my faulty solution?  StackOverflow prefers that over a link only.

Comment: I updated your answer with iPad support (adding `onClick=”return true;”` to the menu divs) and a fix for the overlapping transparent menus (adding `z-index: 1;` to the first menu): http://jsfiddle.net/nxq55ppr/4. 

But in Chrome on Android the first menu item is autoselected. Any idea why?

Comment: I couldn't test it on Android, but on my Chrome, the menu stay hidden, no autoselected.

Comment: In desktop Chrome it works like it should.  On Android Chrome, when I click on the menu, the first item is automatically selected.  Annoying...

Comment: If you figure out the last part, there's a bounty waiting for you at   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28601716/how-can-i-avoid-the-first-item-in-a-pure-css-pull-down-menu-to-be-auto-selected :)